# how to get the data of the column of a gridview of an asp:Linkbutton?

Tags: asp.net

i have a gridview in which in every row there is a checkbox and a linkbutton..when i will check the checkbox i want to get the text of the checkboxes..but by my code i am getting null in the text of the linkbutton...
my code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView5" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"  runat="server" onpageindexchanging = "GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" PageSize="6"  BorderStyle="Ridge" CssClass="grid" CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None"  >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="FileCheckBox"  runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contest Name">   
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton Text='<%#Eval("Contest Name")%>' PostBackUrl='<%# String.Format("Dynamic.aspx?ID=3&filepath={0}",  Eval("Contest Name")   ) %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="250px" CssClass="itemstyle"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
       </asp:GridView>
```

where i am retrieving the text

```
 for (int i = 0; i < GridView5.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)GridView5.Rows[i].FindControl("FileCheckBox");
        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string probname = GridView5.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
         }
   }
```

here i am getting the string of probname as null??

Answer (score 1):

Simple

Just Replace Your Check box code inside template field with

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="FileCheckBox"   AutoPostBack="True"  OnCheckedChanged="someMethod" Text='<%#Eval("Names") %>'  runat="server" />
```

and add this on Server Side

```
protected  void someMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView5.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("FileCheckBox");
                if (chk.Checked == true)
                {
                    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                    conn.Open();
                    string probname = chk.Text;
                }

            }


        }
```

Comment: can i get the text of the linkbutton of that row which checkbox is checked without doing your given anser??

Comment: yes You can get that row as i specified `item` is the row for that grid view